# TypeScript: Non-Null Assertion Operators with []

Tags: typescript

I'm aware that I can use the `!.` syntax to assert that an object has a certain property as follows:

```js
type Person = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  gender?: string;
}

const myPerson: Person = {
  name: 'John Cena',
  age: 123,
  gender: 'sth'
}

const myFunction = (person: Person) => {
  checkIfPersonHasGender(person);
  return person!.gender;
}
```

How do we do that for properties for which keys are in `""` such as the following?:

```
type Person = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  "my-gender"?: string;
}
```

I have tried using `myPerson!.["my-gender"]` but ts gives me an `Identifier expected` error.

Comment: The `!` goes *after* the thing that can be null, not before. It's the opposite of the nullish coalescing operator `?.`

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that `myPerson["my-gender"]` is always defined, you can use TypeScript's [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) feature to tell TypeScript that `myPerson["my-gender"]` will never be `undefined`.

##### Type Assertion Syntax

```ts
// without type assertion
myPerson["my-gender"]; // type  string | undefined

// using default type assertion syntax
myPerson["my-gender"] as string; // type  string

// using angle-bracket type assertion syntax
<string> myPerson["my-gender"]; // type  string
```